# Windows borderless form won't change location

Tags: c#, forms, flash

I have a borderless form that I would like to change the location of programmatically. I have tried a couple of different things and nothing seems to work. What is odd is if I go into the properties for the form, manually change the location to 100,100, set the `StartPosition` to manual, it still starts at 0,0. Another note is that the form only has one control and it's a Flash player control. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it. Any thoghts on why it wouldn't move the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the location through the `Load` event of the Form.

```
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Location = new Point(400, 600);
}
```

EDIT1: posting a full example, in response to the author's comment. This works correctly for me.

**Form1.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var flash = new AxShockwaveFlash();
        Controls.Add(flash);
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        Location = new Point(400, 600);
    }
}
```

**Form1.Designer.cs**

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
        this._axShockwaveFlash = new AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this._axShockwaveFlash)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // flash
        // 
        this._axShockwaveFlash.Enabled = true;
        this._axShockwaveFlash.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this._axShockwaveFlash.Name = "_axShockwaveFlash";
        this._axShockwaveFlash.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("flash.OcxState")));
        this._axShockwaveFlash.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(192, 192);
        this._axShockwaveFlash.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(486, 299);
        this.Controls.Add(this._axShockwaveFlash);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this._axShockwaveFlash)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }

    #endregion

    private AxShockwaveFlash _axShockwaveFlash;

}
```

Comment: Could you show us some code? If nothing works, could you try to create (temporarily) a new form with the same control (but without any other logic in code-behind) and set its position?

Comment: This did not work..                                            private void FlashForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      this.Location = new Point(100, 100);
}..

Comment: It won't work through the normal properties so I don't have any code.

Comment: Are you using an `AxShockwaveFlash` control?

Comment: Yes I am using AxShockwaveFlash

Comment: @Gary I've added an example, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I have the flash player as a existing control on the form and I can't remove it without other problems. I did add the StartPosition and Location in the constructor and it still doesn't change the starting position

Comment: I have added the control in the designer and it still works correctly for me. I don't see how you can't remove it without other problems, since you said that you don't have any code. Either way, I'm posting the automatically generated partial `Form1` class, so you can compare it with yours, if you want. If you still can't solve your problem, please provide some code.

Comment: What I meant about no code was, I don't have any code that relates to the problem because I'm using the standard properties in the forms designer. I'll check out the differences if any and let you know. Thanks